# Injection of autowired dependencies failed (spring and hibernate)

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf-2, annotations

i found many topics about my error but not the same situation so i don't thing that this subject is duplicated.

**here is the controller:**

```
@ManagedBean
@Named
public class UserController {

    @Inject
    public UserManager userManager;
...
}
```

**Dao:**

```
@Named
@Transactional("transactionManager")
public class UserDAO {

    @Inject
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    //...
}
```

**User manager :**

```
@Named
public class UserManager {

    @Inject
    public UserDAO userDAO;
    //...
}
```

UserModel (ModelView):

```
public class UserModel {

    private String login;
    private String pwd;
    private String pwdConfirm;
    //...
}
```

One to Many relation :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role", catalog = "dbusiness")
public class Role  implements java.io.Serializable  {

    private int roleId;
    private String code;
    private String label;
    private User user;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user", catalog = "dbusiness")
public class User  implements java.io.Serializable  {

    private int userId;
    private String login;
    private String pwd;
    private Integer enabled;
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>(0);

}
```

User can have many roles, and one role can be affected in the sime time to many users, that's why i used One to many relation, i didn't put all lignes of code because of stackOverflow rules :p

So when i start tomcat server i get this error message :

```
 Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public com.keylesson.manager.UserManager com.keylesson.controller.UserController.userManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public com.keylesson.dao.UserDAO com.keylesson.manager.UserManager.userDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.keylesson.dao.UserDAO.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="com.keylesson.persistence.User"/>
```

Comment: yes of course :  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
 </dependency>

Comment: Thank's but i still have the same issue :D

Comment: im using 4.1.8.Final,i already use ibernate-commons-annotations in pom file :)

Comment: Do you want your beans be managed by java ee or spring? If spring, use `@Service` for your manager/service classes and `@Repository` for your DAO classes  and `@Autowired` for injection. For Java EE use `@Singleton` annotation on your DAO and service/manager... So in your case, try using the `@Singleton` annotation on the UserManager and UserDao class

Comment: yeah im using Spring Ioc

Comment: Do you have a `LocalSessionFactoryBean` in your Spring configuration?  If yes, add `<property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration"/>` to it.

Comment: i added configurationClass property but i still have many the same issue :(